# Indent paragraph to horizontally align with enumerate environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, indentation, enumitem

I have an enumerated list with points, intersected with comments to each point. I would like to align my comments vertically with the itemized points in the enumerated list. Below a MWE with its output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=left, label=\large{\textbf{\arabic*}}]
    \item Here is my first point.
\end{enumerate}
\textbf{C:} Here is my comment to the first point.
\begin{enumerate}[resume, align=left, label=\large{\textbf{\arabic*}}]
    \item Here is my second point.
\end{enumerate}
\textbf{C:} Here is my comment to the second point.
\end{document}
```

[image]

My desired output would be something like this (ignore the curly braces):

> **1** { } Here is my first point.
>
> **C** { } Here is my comment to the first point.
>
> **2** { } Here is my second point.
>
> **C** { } Here is my comment to the second point.

---

**Edit:** As David & Werner suggest:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\citem}{\item[\textbf{C:}]}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=left, label=\large{\textbf{\arabic*}}]
    \item Here is my first point.
    \citem Here is my comment to the first point.
    \item Here is my second point.
    \citem Here is my comment to the second point.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @lockstep Is my understanding of horizontal and vertical alignment wrong here? I assumed that when you want to align items on a (invisible or visible) horizontal line, that's horizontal alignment, and when you want to align items on a (invisible or visible) vertical line, that's vertical alignment. Since I aim to accomplish the latter, I thought it would be vertical, and not horizontal, alignment.

Comment: You can use an `\indent`, as the `enumitem` package uses `\parindent` to set the indentation of the items

Comment: @MarioS.E. I tried that, i.e. ``\textbf{C:}\indent``. It doesn't align with the itemized list, plus there's no indentation when the comment continues on a second line.

Comment: @Sverre Your understanding is wrong indeed. Horizontal alignment is about alinging elements at a certain horizontal position.

Comment: I think, typographically speaking, it might be better *not* to vertically/horizontally align the comments with the list items. By having them offset, like you had originally, you give valuable visual information to your readers that "this is a comment, not to be confused with another list item".

Comment: In light of [Consistent typography](http://goo.gl/792Wc), and depending on the usages, define something like `\newcommand{\citem}{\item[\textbf{C:}]}` and use `\citem My comment`.

Comment: @lockstep I actually don't understand that. A one-dimensional point is neither vertical or horizontal, only a two-dimensional line is. I'm willing to accept that aligning items on a vertical line is horizontal alignment, but that's confusing terminology to me ... :-/

Comment: @Sverre Maybe think of it like this: aligning things vertically involves sliding them up or down, while aligning things horizontally involves sliding them left or right.

Comment: @Sverre, the items and comments display their first character/letter at a certain $x$ coordinate. You want these coordinates to be the same. The $x$-axis is the horizontal axis, hence horizontal alignment. But anyway, its just terminology.

Comment: @JohnWickerson, typographically speaking, wouldn't it be even better to have the comments indented a bit more then the items. Since they depend on the item above them (as opposed to introducing the item below them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a single `enumerate` environment and use `\item[C:]` for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to define a list-like environment with the appropriate settings for the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mycomm}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mycomm]{align=left,label=\bfseries C:}
\newcommand\mycomment[1]{%
  \begin{mycomm}\item#1\end{mycomm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=left, label=\large\bfseries\arabic*]
    \item Here is my first point.
\end{enumerate}
\mycomment{Here is my comment to the first point.}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
    \item Here is my second point.
\end{enumerate}
\mycomment{Here is my comment to the second point.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that `\large` doesn't take arguments. Using `resume*` you don't have to specify again the previous settings.